# C# Design of the transparent form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-interface

There are some problems and design of the transparent form: 
1. I can not move form over an empty form-space 
2. I can move the form by letters, but not even for the label 
3. The text is distorted against a light background, if it is light. 
4. The text is distorted on a dark background, if it is dark.

If you help, I attach the file with the corrected design, can anyone need it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDI+ only allows to mask one color and to smoothly render text, you need more than one color.

Is Windows Forms really necessary? You may want to switch to WPF, which supports full transparency.

Comment: Of course one couls reverse the argument and ask: Is the transparency necessary..?

Comment: I guess in this case it is. At least for the person who designed this screen.

Comment: @MaxPlay i need a custom library for winforms, without using wpf :c

Comment: @Behavior what kind of library?

Comment: @MaxPlay I don't know, I just assumed that this library exists

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Is there a library or not?

Comment: @MaxPlay sorry for my bad english :c I meant that I'm looking for such a library.

Comment: Okay, why are you not using WPF in the first place?

Comment: @MaxPlay Because my project is big and there Windows Forms is used everywhere. I do not want to rewrite it.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't know any library that is capable of doing such thing in GDI+.